# How may I SELECT the right row for my trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm new to Stored procedures and triggers. After doing an `UPDATE` to my `LeaveRequest` table for a specific row, I have the following trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[LeaveRequestTrig]

 ON  [dbo].[LeaveRequest]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StateId int

SET @StateId = (SELECT LeaveRequest.LeaveRequestStateId FROM LeaveRequest)

IF (@StateId = 2)   
    PRINT 'yes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'no'

END
```

But here's the problem, how may I `SELECT` the row that has just been `UPDATE`d if I don't have the same parameters as the last Query?

Say that my `UPDATE` was for `user = kade` and where `id = 55` how may I SELECT the same row in my trigger?

Comment: This may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pseudo-tables called `DELETED` and `INSERTED` available to you inside trigger, you can get the updated ID(s) there. Note that in general case, there may be multiple rows updated in one query and therefore you may get multiple rows in the `DELETED` and `INSERTED` pseudo-tables.

Comment: The second part of your statement is what bothers me really, I do get an error message stating that it returns more than one value. But I have only UPDATEd one row with specific parameters, how may I retrieve this specific row with those two pseudo-tables? EDIT: I forgot to update the trigger ! It seems to work, thank you !

Comment: Print all the retrieved values and see what they are in `inserted` and `deleted` to see what happened. Also, for UPDATE there will be a record in both `deleted` *and* `inserted` pseudo-tables - one with old values, the other with updated values.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SET @StateId = (SELECT LeaveRequest.LeaveRequestStateId FROM Inserted)
```

for more reference [Trigger insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247679/sql-server-trigger-insert-values-from-new-row-into-another-table).
For you concern about returning multiple rows,follow this link that shows [how to join the psuedotables to get single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197546/trigger-causes-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value)